# Can two networks with the same subnet be connected to the same router in different VRF?

Tags: bgp, vrf

Let's say I have the following four networks:

- Network A: 10.0.1.0/24
- Network B: 10.0.0.0/24
- Network C: 10.0.1.0/24
- Network D: 10.0.0.0/24

I would like to connect networks A and B together, and do the same between C and D (while A/B can't access C/D). With only a single router, could this be configured by setting two different VRF as shown below ?

[image]

If yes, what would happens if I set up BGP to exchange route between the two VRF, like in the following link: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/multiprotocol-label-switching-mpls/multiprotocol-label-switching-vpns-mpls-vpns/47807-routeleaking.html#diffvrfs

Comment: For overlapping networks to communicate, you would need to use NAT. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/41663/8499) and answers about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two questions here.

> Can two networks with the same subnet be connected to the same router
>   in different VRF?

Yes, as long as the two domains (VRF A and VRF B) do not communicate with each other. Think of a VRF as a virtual router.

> What would happens if I set up BGP to exchange route between the two
>   VRF?

Things will not work, because hosts on Net A will never see hosts on C, and vice versa.  Same for B and D.